# The trackpad doesn't work when starting Windows 7 bootcamp

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, trackpad

I installed Windows 7 (bootcamp) on my MacBook but it doesn't work. Do I have to install special drivers?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check out [TrackPad++](http://trackpad.powerplan7.com/). It's free with an option to donate.

I've used this in the past, when I had bootcamp with Windows 7 - you can set gestures like you can in Mac OS X.

Comment: I successfully installed TrackPad++ but still doesn't work.